# Spring 4 upgrade - now missing class CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor

Tags: spring

The following import statement fails:

```
import org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor;
```

This class used to reside in spring-web jar file in Spring 3, but now I've upgraded to use Spring 4 I cannot find this class file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class has been replaced by `org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor`  (see [source](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/744585-commonshttpinvokerrequestexecutor-in-spring-4-0)).

See also the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/httpinvoker/HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.html).

Comment: it seems it will need a re-implementation after upgrading as the issue is not solved by only replacing this class. Any details about the re-implementation?